# Tweet when another user is tweeting

Tags: web-apps, scheduling, twitter

Is there a Web app in which I can schedule a tweet to another user but having it posted only when that other user seems to be active on Twitter?

(If this app doesn't exist, I'll consider building it if enough people want it. If you are amongst those that want it, please, check this out: http://goo.gl/forms/pScXGyYNUw)

Comment: Hmm. Very interesting. When you say "active on twitter" do you mean like actively tweeting/replying? Also will this scheduled tweet be the same every time?

Comment: Yes, I mean actively tweeting/replying, so as to maximize the chances of them seeing the tweet. I have an idea of how to measure the activity should I end up building this product. My idea is for the tweet to be posted once.

Comment: @Pablo If you are going to build, want a collaborator?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a dedicated app to what you are wanting to do, but more like a workaround. You can use a web service called If This Than That ([IFTTT](https://ifttt.com)). IFTTT basically allows connection between two services (also called **channels**) by creating a **trigger** on one service and an **action** on another.

So in your case, you would create a "New tweet by another user" **trigger** and a "Post a tweet" **action**.
 
Some caveats to using this service; it's limited to specific triggers and actions and doesn't really have much control beyond that. Other than seeing if the user has tweeted, there really isn't much of a way to measure specific activity. You also mentioned in the comments that you only wanted to run this once, which isn't possible in IFTTT unfortunately. Recipes are either on or off.

Steps to creating a **recipe**:

1. If you don't have an account, make one now
2. Browse to "My Recipes" and click on the big blue "Create a recipe" button
3. Search for the "Twitter" channel and select it (you might have to connect the twitter channel, IFTTT should walk you through this process)
4. Select "New tweet by a specific user" and enter in the twitter handler
5. Search for the Twitter channel again
6. Select "Post a tweet" action and enter in the tweet that you want to tweet (which can include a user mention)